# Non router VPN host hardware ?

Tags: networking, vpn

**SHORT QUESTION**

Is there such thing as a non router VPN host that i can plug into a network and allow it to act as a IPSEC over LT2P VPN host ?

**LONG QUESTION**
We have a Draytek 2860 router which is also acting as a VDSL modem.

We are trying to setup the Draytek as an ISPEC over LT2P VPN, but for some reason it wont work, Ive set this up many times on a Draytek 2860 and 2862, but for some reason this unit wont work, my self and 2 others have tried and all come to the same conculsion.

We have been able to get a PPTP connection to work, but as this is un secure we dont want to use it.

Is there such thing as a non router VPN host that i can plug into a network and allow it to act as a IPSEC over LT2P VPN host ?

We want to retain the Draytek router as we have all of our settings already configured on it, but just want a VPN host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the word 'router' **does not imply** that the device has to be the whole network's default router; second, "VPN hosts" are still routers by definition. You can always have the Draytek router providing DHCP and acting as a gateway to Internet, *and* another router acting as just a VPN server.

Of course, you can configure any generic computer (anything from rack server to Raspberry Pi) to act as a VPN server instead. (That'd still make it become a "router" as part of the process.)